# How to run batch file on remote server

Tags: batch-file, ssis

I am using 2 machine one local and other remote from local I have used SSIS package to execute batch file on remote server using wmi process but my problem is that batch file is executing locally instead of remote

Answer (score 1):

Check out System Internals which was bought by Microsoft in the mid 200X.

I used the **psexec** command to run remote batch files via VB script.  I am sure you can do the same with SSIS.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx

You need rights of course on the remote machine (RM1) and a local copy of psexec.

```
psexec \\RM1 cmd
```

This test code runs a command prompt on the remote machine.  Parameters like user/pwd will have to be passed.

Good luck in you coding efforts.